# Using jQuery for JSON web service

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I'm trying to use geopages.org api to populate a city input field onblur of my zip code input field. I don't know what the problem is with my script.

```
<script>

$("#zip").blur(function() {
var city = $("#city");
var zip = $("#zip");

$.getJSON("http://www.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=" + zip.val + "&country=US&username=myusername?", function(json){
 data = json.postalcodes[0].placeName;
 city.val(text);                    
});
}
});

</script>
```

I'm pretty sure it's a syntax error but my jQuery is not that good so I don't know where my issue is.

Comment: can you take all of your code to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: make sure the API is returning JSONP other wise if it is straight json you'll need a proxy or service like YQL to get the data first

Comment: I'm new to this JSON and JSONP stuff. [This](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#postalCodeLookupJSON) is the api i'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one more `}` than needed, try this:

```
$("#zip").blur(function() {
var city = $("#city");
var zip = $("#zip");

$.getJSON("http://www.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=" + zip.val + "&country=US&username=myusername?", function(json){
 data = json.postalcodes[0].placeName;
 city.val(text);                    
});
});
```

Comment: Here's a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WmtCr/1/. The only thing I can see as the reason for this not working is if you did not enable your free web service. Uncomment the `alert` to see the message if an error occurred. Of course, replace the `username` with a valid username... Note I used the example from their side, i.e. it's a call with fixed parameters - you should change back to what you had, changed as I put it in the answer to read back from your `zip`.

Comment: Does it matter that you're using a text area in jsfiddle but that I'm using a text box in my application?

Comment: Weird...I can't get the jsfiddle to work on Safari but it works in Firefox.

Comment: Weird indeed.. Should not matter and should work in both - yes, I'm on Firefox, so this might be something Safari-specific (don't have it to try, sorry).

Comment: No problem. Question. Even on Firefox I can't get my version with the dynamic parameter to work. Can it be something related to my web host maybe?

Comment: You need to use `$('#zip').val()` to get the value of the zip - doing without `.val()` will get you the jQuery wrapper around the DOM object only. Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/WmtCr/6/, just replace your `username` and click in and out of the text box - you should get San Diego.

Comment: Awesome! That makes perfect sense. Still doesn't work on my server though :(. Any other ideas? Works perfectly in jsfiddle.

Comment: There can be a lot of things that can go wrong - did you include jQuery, do you do everything in onload (i.e. `$(function() { ... }`), etc. My advice - read through the code to see you don't have any syntax errors, break it into small pieces, try to mimic what's on jsFiddle as that's working. Hope something will work out for you!

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll do just that.

Comment: One last thing. I don't think i do it in onload and i think that's my issue. Honestly i don't even know how to do that or why it's necessary. Care to explain?

Comment: Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/WmtCr/17/. This wraps it in `$(function() { ... }`. Try copying this code locally and running - should work. To read more about this: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()

Comment: Great. Good stuff. Thank you. That still didn't work so I must've overlooked something. I'll play around with it some more tonight. Thanks for all your help.